# Run PhantomJS script when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, node.js, phantomjs

**Context**: I was scraping some websites with NodeJS/jQuery and I was getting troubles, because I wanted some elements of the page that were dinamically generated. Then, I researched about it and found out that PhantomJS is a better option for this case.
*~Wohoooo, Great.~*

Now what I want is to build a really simple website (only a button?) just to execute this PhantomJS.

Code example of what am I doing:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
page.open('https://website.that.Iam.scraping.com', function(status) { ...
```

And I am calling this PhantomJS in bash like:

```
phantomjs scraper.js
```

**Desired result**:
The simple UI webpage with a button (that runs phantomjs script) and the result of the script appearing at the webpage as well.

**Question**: how could I run this PhantomJS when a button is clicked? Is it possible?

PS: I was thinking to create the website in Ruby. Is it a good option?

Thanks a lot in advance, guys!
Have a nice day!

Comment: When a button is clicked on the page that you do not own?  You'll need to iterate over everything you're interested in (use X Path probably) and attach a listener which stops propogation and triggers some log message which your phantom script can grab.

Comment: _When a button is clicked on the page that you do not own?_
The button is at my webpage, and it runs the phantomjs (that scrapes another page).
XPath could do that? ("Activate" a phantomjs script?).
But how could I attach this listener to my webpage?

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you want is a simple web page with one button, you click it, it talks to the server and the server run the phantomjs script and get the result, then send it back to the your web page.

**Yes, it is definitely possible.**

1. First make sure your phantomjs script does what you want on its own, it should works fine when being called on command line
2. Then you need to build a request handler on the server side, it will accept your button click request, call phantomjs(by spawning a new sub-process for phantomjs, and wait for its execution, get its result when it is done, just think your server side code as a simple bash command line), send back the result and display it on your page.

Ruby is fine to build such thing.

Comment: Definitely you got it! 
Just a question about you mentioned: how to make this phantomjs call on the server-side?
I mean, let's suppose I have a _server.js_ running locally. 
Within this file, I would have the button request handler, calling the _phantomjs_.

Comment: Thus, the _phantomjs_ does what it has to do, give back the info to the _server.js_.
Finally I get this info from the server and I display at the webpage.
Do you mean this flow? Thanks for your reply, man!

Comment: With node.js, you could check the [child process doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), you will know how to call external program(here it's your phantomjs script), and you could also get output from the phantomjs scripts by reading from  `child.stdout`, for ruby, that's almost the same thing.

Comment: I followed what you mentioned, but I think I'm missing some concept.
**Where I am:** now I have the server running and calling the phantomjs script. I get the results from the phantom script (but in console). **What I want:** I wanna call this method (that is the server file) by the click of the button, and display these results that I see in console at the webpage. Do you know how could I do that?

Comment: @FelpS. Keep in mind that we don't like chameleon questions where the asker continually asks followup questions. If you can't solve it on your own, you can ask a new question (Stack Overflow is not for discussions). Considering your issue: since I don't know your code, it looks like you're simply writing something to the console. I know that in PHP console and page content are not separate, but in other languages those are separate and you can have both: writing some logs to the console and building up the DOM for the HTML output at the same time.